# ¿existe una forma de subir una imagen y que se adapte a un recuadro dado en un pdf usando pdfTron?

Tags: angular, imagen, pdf

Empecé a trabajar en un código que ya estaba hecho y usaron el sdk
de pdfTron para editar un pdf, lo que quieren lograr es que al subir una imagen se ajuste al tamaño automático que tiene cada cuadro para imágenes. Permítanme explicar: en la imagen que muestro hay varios marcos destinados para que el usuario inserte su imagen allí, si el usuario selecciona subir su imagen al cuadro # 1 entonces la imagen tendría que adaptarse al tamaño del cuadro # 1 , Estoy comenzando en un trabajo, todavía no tengo mucha experiencia, no sé si es porque no tengo mucha experiencia que no encuentro cómo hacerlo o por eso que quiren lograr no es factible de esta forma. Me gustaría leer la opinión de alguien con experiencia, estoy leyendo la documentación de pdfTron pero no encuentro algo que me ayude. Habría una forma de detectar el tamaño de cuadro del pdf destinado para las fotos y hacer que la imagen se adapte a ese tamaño. ¿cómo podría hacerlo? una mejor forma de hacerlo?

a continuación dejo una imágen para que se aprecie mejor:

[image: enes]

Comment: Si tu espacio va a ser dinámico y tienes que leer directo de el pdf el espacio, agrega ese espacio como otra imagen, según la documentación puedes obtener las dimensiones de un elemento imagen dentro de el documento.

Comment: Tomas las medidas que tenga ese recuadro y redimensionas tu imagen y la incrustas. y Esta es la documentación donde vienen esas referencias

Comment: [PDFNet.Element.getImageHeight](https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/PDFNet.Element.html#getImageHeight__anchor)  , [PDFNet.Element.getImageWidth](https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/PDFNet.Element.html#getImageWidth__anchor)

Comment: trato de entender la documentación, pero se me hace difícil. crees que sería mejor construir el pdf desde un html usando alguna librería de angular? básicamente lo que se quiere es armar como una revista digital, donde el usuario pueda editar algunos textos y subir imágenes arrastrándolas desde una parte de la página hacia a cada hoja de la revista.

Comment: la única manera que se me ocurre donde te respete todos los estilos que ingreses a la plantilla es que al final generes una imagen de cada hoja y la insertes al pdf.

Comment: Por que lo dices? se que hay librerías en Angular que te convierten el html a un PDF pero no he trabajado con ellas. Una duda que se me ocurrió es como hacer para generar una hoja con cada plantilla, tendría n plantillas para n cantidades de hojas del PDF ? tu has trabajado antes con el PDF tron amigo ?

Comment: ¿Su pregunta es cómo cambiar el tamaño / escalar la imagen? ¿O tu pregunta es cómo determinar el tamaño del cuadro de destino?